# FLUTTER /SPRING BOOT - SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE

Tags: flutter, spring-boot, ssl

I am facing an issue where I am unable to contact specific endpoints in my Spring Boot application from my Flutter app. The error message I receive is an SSL handshake failure with SSL error code -1 and net_error 202.

Here are some additional details:

I have a Spring Boot application serving various endpoints, and most of them work fine when accessed from Flutter.
However, there are a few specific endpoints that consistently result in an SSL handshake failure when accessed from my Flutter app.
The same endpoints are accessible without any issues when I test them using tools like Postman.
I have implemented a custom HttpOverrides class in Flutter to bypass SSL verification, but it does not resolve the issue.

I have checked the network connectivity and ensured that the device/emulator can access the server.
The problem is that it never happened in the past days...

````
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    HttpClient httpClient = super.createHttpClient(context);
    httpClient.badCertificateCallback =
        (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
// Enable SSL debug logs

    return httpClient;
  }
}

class _HealthAPIConnectWidgetState extends State<HealthAPIConnectWidget> {
  static String BASE_URL = "https://192.168.0.22:443";
  late WebViewController _controller;
  final Set<Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>> gestureRecognizers = {
    Factory(() => EagerGestureRecognizer())
  };

  @override
  Future<void> initState() async {
    super.initState();

    HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
    _controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(Colors.white)
      ..setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(
        onProgress: (int progress) {},
        onPageStarted: (String url) {},
        onPageFinished: (String url) {},
        onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
          if (request.url.startsWith("${BASE_URL}/confirm.html")) {
            widget.onAccountLinked(true);
          } else if (request.url.startsWith("${BASE_URL}/alreadyassociated.html")) {
            widget.onAccountLinked(false);
          }
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
      ))
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse("${BASE_URL}/connect/auth/${widget.userIdentifier}"));
  }```

 I checked and the device and the server are in the same network
````